# Setting section headers in R file that get rendered with spin()

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Traditionally I declare section headers in Rmd files like this:

````
# header 1
```{r, echo=FALSE}
print("foo")
```

## header level 2
```{r}
print("bar")
```
````

So that when it gets rendered to HTML, it looks like this. And I can put in a table of contents.

## header 1

```
foo
```

### header level 2

```
bar
```

Using the spin() function, I would like to generate a Rmd file from a R ('Main.R') file that has the proper headers in knitr. Currently if I have this R file:

```
#+ section_1, echo=F
# what do I put here so that "header 1" gets inserted into the spun Rmd?
print("foo")

#+ section_2
print("bar")
```

Spinning with `spin('Main.R', knit=F)` produces this:

````
```{r section_1, echo=F}
# what do I put here so that "header 1" gets inserted into the spun Rmd?
print("foo")

```{r section_2}
print("bar")
```
````

I could not find any documentation that suggests how to insert the section names?

Comment: I doubt if there's a way. The theory would be, if you want to write a full markdown document, then run `spin` and subsequently edit the output. It sounds as if you want to mix R text and markdown... but for this we have .Rmd files. What's the use case?

Comment: The use case is the same as the driver for using spin(). Have written R file, would love to continue to be able to source() it, but would also like to generate a report from it. The addition of section headers would allow the creation of a proper table of contents, which improves usability of the HTML report significantly. Editing the Rmd is not a good solution because it would mean maintaining 2 files - the .R and the .Rmd.

Comment: The idea of vignettes is that you can mix readable text with executable code.  Rmd files are close enough to vignettes for this:  just use `knitr::purl("source.Rmd")` to produce `source.R`, and source that.  The `source.Rmd` file is the true source, the `source.R` file is an intermediate.  You only ever edit `source.Rmd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include Roxygen comments in .R files.  For example,

```
#' ## Section 1
print("foo")

#' ## Section 2
print("bar")
```

If you want to, you can include a full YAML header such as

```
#' ---
#' title: My document in a .R file
#' output:
#'   html_document: 
#'     toc: true
#' ---
#'
```

but you'll probably need to use `rmarkdown::render` instead of `knitr::spin`.

Comment: Can the header include a variable R object, and how do you format that?

Comment: @user42485:  Yes, e.g. `#' title: "`r thetitle`"`. (where there are backticks just inside the two double quotes; they're rendering as blanks for me).